# Combining two numberPicker values hours and minutes into a countdown timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I have defined two separate methods that set the value of the numberPickers to the value of the text in my countdown timer. The only problem is that I can only set the timer to either hours or minutes, but I am not able to combine the two values. How could I combine these two methods to make one that combines the two values.

Here is the two methods...

```
noPickerHours.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            timer = new CounterClass((newVal * 60 * 1000), 1000);
            long millis = (newVal * 60 * 1000);
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            textViewTime.setText(hms);
        }
    });

    noPickerMinutes.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            timer = new CounterClass((newVal * 60 * 1000), 1000);
            long millis = (newVal * 60 * 1000);
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            textViewTime.setText(hms);
        }
    });
```

Thanks to anyone who helps :)

Comment: Are you converting the hours to millisencos right? `long millis = (newVal * 60 * 1000);` shouldn't be `long millis = (newVal *60 * 60 * 1000);`? Also, you are doing the operatin to times, move the varible upper the timer and use it to declare the timer.

Comment: Im not quite sure what your trying to say could you elaborate on that

Comment: I said that in your hour datepicker you convert the value like this `long millis = (newVal * 60 * 1000);` but if they are hours it should be like this `long millis = (newVal * 60 * 60 * 1000);` isn't it? That's not going to fix the problem because you overwrite the values but if you confirm that I could make an example using variables to save the values.

Comment: Yes you are correct it should be (newVal * 60 * 60 * 1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, why don't you save the state of the datapicker in variables to use them in the other one? (I suppose seconds are always 0 because you don't change them in your code)

```
int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;
private void setTimer () {
    timer = new CounterClass((hours *60 * 60 * 1000) + (minutes * 60 *1000), 1000);
    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:00", ), hours, minutes);
    textViewTime.setText(hms);
}
...
noPickerHours.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        hours = newVal;
        setTimer();
    }
});

noPickerMinutes.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        minutes = newVal;
        setTimer();
    }
});
```

Edit, I forget to add the vars to the timer

Comment: This still is either counting down one or the other it won't countdown both at the same time

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add the vars to the timer creation.

Comment: could you able to share your complete code for countdown timer with number picker?